# How to change WebStorm enviroment settings for File Watcher?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, nvm

I have simple File Watcher that run TSLint. If I copy the command and run it in the console all fine but WebStorm run it with old Node version and throw error `Buffer.alloc is not a function`.

I'm using nvm to manage node.js versions.

ubuntu 16.4

[image]

Comment: `Buffer.alloc` just supported by nodejs version `5.10.0` or higher.

Comment: what OS is it, what does your file watcher look like? Please share a screenshot

Comment: @lena see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Different Node.js versions are on your `$PATH` when you start your script from the IDE and from terminal.

When being launched from desktop/System menu, WebStorm only sees environment variables configured in login shell, but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`).
Possible workarounds:

- Workaround 1: make required variables available in a login shell by moving them to the corresponding shell profile config
- Workaround 2: run IDE from a terminal, either with the command line launcher or with `bin/webstorm.sh`
- Workaround 3: edit the desktop launcher and set command to `/path/to/shell -l -i -c  "/path/to/webstorm.sh"` (make sure that the shell you specified there has the needed variables configured in its interactive shell configuration file)

see also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589